# Extended web application low performances

Tags: 2013, web-application, extended

A customer is using SP 2013 and I can see he extended his unique web application to another IIS site (for external access).

This is his configuration :

- 1 SP Server hosting C.A + Intranet Website 12GB RAM
- 1 SP Server hosting Extranet Website with 16GB RAM
- 1 SQL Server - SQL is limited to 2GB RAM while it has 16GB

In fact, both sites are hosting by the two IIS. But external accesses are redirected to the 2nd SP Server.

Customers are encoutering low performances against both sites.

So I would advice him to **up the limit for SQL**, and **restart the SP Server** hosting CA (41days uptime and restart required in event vwr and finally **limit memory usage for noderunner.exe**.

My question is : Extend a web app does not low the perfs, right ?

Answer (score 1):

As per your Specification, your problem is SQL Server not the SP server.

Extended web application can cause the load on the Server if you create a new app pool for it otherwise it is a website.

2GB for the SQL is nothing, you should increase the SQL memory at leaset 8GB( which is recommended for small farm).
check this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.15).aspx#section3

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there's only 1 app pool. So SQL is the only thing that limits the performances. When I end up testing, I'll come back to post feedback. Thanks @Waqas.

Comment: I've up the SQL RAM limit to 8Gb, according to users navigation still slow and file opening too. Files may depend on network connection too I guess. But SQL blobs are disabled, what if I enabled them ? this will take huge disk space ? I also have to check that disk is formatting in 64k on the SQL server but I'm not sure how much it will increase performances.